# In what contexts might one say "風呂{ふろ}" instead of "お[風呂]{ふろ}"?

Tags: honorifics

In what contexts might "風呂" be used instead of "お風呂"? "お巡りさん" has been lexicalized. "お茶" is almost lexicalized. What about "お風呂"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head....

1. In scholarly and/or technical writing regarding bathing or baths.
2. In advertisement for apartments, describing whether they are equipped with bath tubs or not.
3. In the news about a bathroom.

Regardless of the context, many male speakers choose to use 「風呂」 over 「お風呂」 on a daily basis.